# Webbrowser : get source of webpage while navigating

Tags: c#, browser

I want to get source of webpage or `document.body.innerhtml` while the page is navigating.

I test this code:

```
textbox1.Text=Webbrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHTML;
```

but there is a problem...
this code work correctly when the page is loaded complete.

I just want to get page source while loading page.

sorry for my English :)

Comment: `but there is a problem` what is that problem.?

Comment: Why exactly do you need to get the page source while the page is loading instead of after the page has finished loading.  Some more context around your question would be helpful.

Comment: @user2365124:why?while loading